# Publishing iOS app.

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have my build uploaded to itunesconnect and I am all ready to go. The only thing I have left to do is to upload the screenshots. My app supports iOS8 and later. According to itunes connect, I need at least one 5.5 display screenshot. I don't have an iphone 6 plus so I don't know how to get the screenshots.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: get simulator through screen shot

Comment: It’s something that can be found easily.

Comment: simulator is the obvious answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Xcode run project in the simulator as iPhone 6 by cmd+R.

Go through the main screen which you want to capture the screenshot by cmd+s.

now open iTunesconnect from browser select + upload app

go to tab ios app submission upload screenshot. Enjoy

if you getting more confuse go through following links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlOdp4uZoo

Answer (score 2):

You can use the iOS Simulator to get the screenshots, you can save the screenshots with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.